# Lift chain complex from $\mathbb{F}_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, linear-algebra, chain-complexes

We start with a finite dimensional chain complex over $\mathbb{F}_2$, equipped with a basis. That is, we have finitely many finite dimensional $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector spaces $C_0,\dots,C_k$ with bases $B_0,\dots,B_k$, and $\mathbb{F}_2$-module maps $d_i\colon C_i\rightarrow C_{i-1}$ with $d_{i-1}d_i=0$. I want to lift this to a chain complex over $\mathbb{Z}$.

(A cleaner restatement in terms of matrices is: we have matrices $M_1,\dots,M_k$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with $M_{i-1}M_i=0$, and I want to lift them to matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying that property.)

Now, this can always be done (for example, by using the structure theorem for chain complexes over $\mathbb{F}_2$). I wanted to know if this can always be done subject to the following restrictions.

Restriction 1: $0$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$ should lift to a $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.
Restriction 2: (Only interested if Restriction 1 can always be achieved) $1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$ should lift to $\pm 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

(I believe, for no particular reason, that Restriction 1 can always be achieved, but not Restriction 2 in addition.)

Clarifications in response to comments: $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the field of two elements (perhaps I should have said $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ throughout).
Explicit restatement: I have matrices $M_1,\dots,M_k$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$ such that for all $i$, the product $M_{i-1}M_i$ is defined and is zero. I want to find integer matrices $N_1,\dots,N_k$ such that for all $i$, $N_{i-1}N_i=0$, and the mod-2 reduction of $N_i$ is $M_i$. I want to ensure that if an entry is zero in $M_i$, then the corresponding entry in $N_i$ is zero. In addition, I wouldn't mind if I can ensure that if an entry is $1$ in $M_i$, then the corresponding entry in $N_i$ is $\pm 1$, but that is perhaps a bit much.

Comment: It'd be a pleasure to consider this topic, but personally I would prefer much more explicit definitions. It'd be perhaps a couple of extra lines, and things would be clearer to me.

Comment: What is $F_2$? If it is the free group of rank $2$, which is what that notation means to me, then what is a chain complex over $F_2$ given that $F_2$ is a nonabelian group?

Comment: @LeeMosher: I took $F_2$ to mean the field of two elements here.

Comment: 1. What is "the structure theorem for chain complexes over F_2"? 2. What does it mean "lift"? I understand it as lifting in the category of vector spaces, so 0 should go to 0 automatically, isn't it?

Comment: @Pasha: every chain complex over a field is isomorphic to a chain complex in which every differential is the composition of a projection out of a direct sum and an inclusion into another direct sum. To lift an object $d$ in a category $d \in D$ through a functor $F : C \to D$ is to find an object $c \in C$ such that $F(c) \cong d$. In this case $C, D$ are chain complexes over $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{F}_2$ respectively and $F$ is tensor with $\mathbb{F}_2$. $0$ refers to a matrix entry and not to an object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not always possible, even just with condition (1). Consider the complex $\mathbb{F}_2^7 \to \mathbb{F}_2^7 \to \mathbb{F}_2^3$ where the basis of the first vector space is indexed by lines of the [Fano plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane), the basis of the second vector space is indexed by points of the Fano plane and the third vectors space is just thought of as $\mathbb{F}_2^3$.

The first map sends a line to the formal sum of the three points on it. The second map embeds the Fano plane as the $7$ nonzero elements of $\mathbb{F}_2^3$. So the composisition is $0$ because, for any line in the Fano plane, the three points on it add up to $0$ considered as vectors in $\mathbb{F}_2^3$.

If you had a lift of the sort you describe, you would have $7$ vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ (the image of the basis vectors of the second $\mathbb{Z}^7$) such that each line of the Fano plane gave three vectors with a linear relation between them. In other words, you would have realized the Fano plane in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{Q})$, which is impossible.

In general, questions about linear algebra while imposing that various matrix entries are zero resemble [Mnev's universality theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnev%27s_universality_theorem), so you should expect everything conceivable to go wrong.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that last remark? I'm afraid I don't see the connection.

Comment: It was deliberately vague, but for example: Suppose I say that $A \vec{v}=0$ where $A$ is a matrix $\vec{v}$ is a vector whose only nonzero entries are in positions $2$, $4$, $5$ and $8$. Then I am saying that rows $A_2$, $A_4$, $A_5$ and $A_8$ are linearly dependent. So I can probably take whatever linear algebra problem you are doing and use it to talk about a bunch of vectors, subsets of which have various linear dependencies. And that is, more or less, a matroid realization space, which is what Mnev's result talks about. I presume you've already read http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411469 ?